# How to preserve html character encodings in URL's

Tags: php, url, get

So I have these long URL's that enter a PHP script through a GET veriable.

```
<?php
$given_url = $_GET['url'];
echo $given_url;
?>
```

Lets say I do
`http://example.com/index.php?url=http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=%24+1+0.000005+10.200277308269968+33+5+43%0Ai+112+320+112+192+0+4%0Ai+416+192+416+320+0+6%0Ar+192+320+192+192+0+1%0Ar+208+192+320+192+0+2%0Ar+336+192+336+320+0+3%0Aw+112+192+192+192+0%0Aw+192+192+208+192+0%0Aw+320+192+336+192+0%0Aw+336+192+416+192+0%0Aw+416+320+336+320+0%0Aw+336+320+192+320+0%0Aw+192+320+112+320+0%0A`

then how do I let the page echo **literaly** what is behind the `http://example.com/index.php?url=` ?

corrently is returns `www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$ 1 0.000005 10.200277308269968 33 5 43 i 112 320 112 192 0 4 i 416 192 416 320 0 6 r 192 320 192 192 0 1 r 208 192 320 192 0 2 r 336 192 336 320 0 3 w 112 192 192 192 0 w 192 192 208 192 0 w 320 192 336 192 0 w 336 192 416 192 0 w 416 320 336 320 0 w 336 320 192 320 0 w 192 320 112 320 0` as if it should process the encoded(?) characters in the URL..

Comment: you could look into using $_POST instead of $_GET

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

Use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
echo urlencode($given_url);
```

Comment: this will result into www.falstad.com%2Fcircuit%2Fcircuitjs.htmlcct%3D%24+1+0.000005+10.200277308269968+33+5+43%0Ai+112+320+112+192+0+4%0Ai+416+192+416+320+0+6%0Ar+192+320+192+192+0+1%0Ar+208+192+320+192+0+2%0Ar+336+192+336+320+0+3%0Aw+112+192+192+192+0%0Aw+192+192+208+192+0%0Aw+320+192+336+192+0%0Aw+336+192+416+192+0%0Aw+416+320+336+320+0%0Aw+336+320+192+320+0%0Aw+192+320+112+320+0%0A

which is still different in the first part of the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
  $given_url = $_GET["url"];
  $pieces = explode("?", $given_url);
  $part1 = $pieces[0];
  $part2 = urlencode($pieces[1]);
  $new_url = $part1.$part2;
  echo $new_url
?>
```

Caveat here is that we are assuming there isn't another "?" somewhere else in the string.

Comment: this still results into
www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.htmlcct=$ 1 0.000005 10.200277308269968 33 5 43 i 112 320 112 192 0 4 i 416 192 416 320 0 6 r 192 320 192 192 0 1 r 208 192 320 192 0 2 r 336 192 336 320 0 3 w 112 192 192 192 0 w 192 192 208 192 0 w 320 192 336 192 0 w 336 192 416 192 0 w 416 320 336 320 0 w 336 320 192 320 0 w 192 320 112 320 0